# When are two complex Tori biholomorphic

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $g \ge 1$ be a natural number and $\mathbb{C}^g$ complex vector space which
is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2g}$ is real vector space.

An additive subgroup $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{C}^g$ is called a
*lattice* if there exist $2g$ vectors $\gamma_1,... \gamma_{2g}$,
which are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$\Gamma= \mathbb{Z} \gamma_1 + ... + \mathbb{Z} \gamma_{2g}$.

Let $\Gamma, \Gamma' \subset \mathbb{C}^g$ two lattices with
$\Gamma= \mathbb{Z} \gamma_1 + ... + \mathbb{Z} \gamma_{2g}$ and
$\Gamma'= \mathbb{Z} \gamma' _1 + ... + \mathbb{Z} \gamma' _{2g}$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491437/isomorphism-between-torus) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316181/when-are-two-tori-biholomorphic) is discussed a characterization when two tori
$\mathbb{C} / \Gamma$ and $\mathbb{C} / \Gamma'$
with lattices $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ are biholomorphic.
The main result states that
$\mathbb{C} / \Gamma$ and $\mathbb{C} / \Gamma'$ are biholomorphic
if and only if there exist a scalar $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^*$
with $\alpha \Gamma = \Gamma'$.

I'm searching for a similar result for $g \ge 2$ which characterizes
for two lattices $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ when the tori
$\mathbb{C}^g / \Gamma $ and $ \mathbb{C}^g / \Gamma'$ are
*biholomorphic*.

Can the quoted result for $g=1$ be generalized?
What is well known is that for arbitrary two lattices $\Gamma, \Gamma' \subset \mathbb{C}^g$ there exist a matix $M \in GL_{2g}(\mathbb{C})$ with $M \cdot \Gamma = \Gamma'$ and $\gamma' _j = M \gamma_j$.

This implies presumably (??) that arbitrary two tori $\mathbb{C}^g / \Gamma $ and $ \mathbb{C}^g / \Gamma'$ as far as $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ are lattices in $\mathbb{C}^g$ are always isomorphic as (abelian) groups and as topological spaces. As far as that's correct, yes?

Now to decide if they are also biholomorphic is more complicated as stated in linked discussions. Is there any neat characterization for $g \ge 2$ in similar manner as for $g=1$?

Comment: In the third from last paragraph, you probably intended $M\in GL_{2g}(\mathbb R)$. I suspect you'll need $M\in GL_g(\mathbb C)$ in order to get the tori biholomorphic.

Comment: You'll find the answer in any book on the subject — Debarre's *Complex Tori and Abelian Varieties* is quite accessible. And again, your questions would be more appropriate at MSE.

Comment: Also on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800744/isomorphic-lattices-complex-tori-and-their-relation-to-jacobians/3803463#3803463